# How do you iterate through an array of indices in a thread-safe, performant way?

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, queue

I have multiple threads that need to write to an Azure queue.  To increase throughput, I've created 8 different Azure queues.  As a result, I have 8 different connection strings stored in a static string[] array.  I'd like to write code that perfectly load balances writing to those queues, by always returning the index of the next queue to write to (and connection string to use), so that queue 0 gets written to the same number of times as queue 1, queue 2, etc. - all in serial succession.  I need a way to iterate through indices 0 through 7, in a way that is thread-safe.  Is there a more performant and efficient way to write the below code, and how do I make it thread-safe?  Thank you very much.

```
    private static int currentQueueIndex = -1; // initial value set to -1 so that index 0 is returned first.
    private static int maxIndex = 7;
    private static int GetNextQueueIndex()
    {
        int tempIndex = currentQueueIndex + 1;
        if (tempIndex > maxIndex)
        {
            currentQueueIndex = 0;
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return tempIndex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't believe this is thread safe the way you have it. define an instance of a simple object, then lock on that instance inside GetNextQueueIndex so that it is thread safe.

Comment: You're just incrementing an int, I'd just wrap it in a `lock`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect job for the `Interlocked` methods, which perform atomic operations on values in memory. This is as fast as you can get when it comes to a globally-visible thread-safe operation.

If you can restrict your queue count to power-of-two numbers, you just mask off the low bits:

```
private static int GetNextQueueIndex()
{
    return Interlocked.Increment(ref currentQueueIndex) & (maxIndex - 1);
}
```

Or, if you have a non-power-of-two number of queues -- but you asked for perf, so I suggest avoiding a div:

```
private static int GetNextQueueIndex()
{
    int i = Interlocked.Increment(ref currentQueueIndex) & Int32.MaxValue;
    return i % maxIndex;
}
```

Note there is no need to reset `currentQueueIndex` back to `0` -- it's perfectly safe to let the storage overflow and mask off just the bits we need.

Comment: did you mean % (modulo division)?

Comment: `& 7` works as well because 7 is 0b111, but % would be clearer.

Comment: And this doesn't store the value mod 7.. which may not matter.

Comment: Cory, thanks very much for the help.  I tried your first solution with the given constants, and found that your first solution works perfectly as long as it's a power-of-two number as you say, but also you have to change (maxIndex - 1) to just (maxIndex).  That way, it iterates perfectly from 0 through 7 and back to 0 again.  Also, your note about storage overflow being ok is correct (I tested it), so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Cory Nelson, the following is the final solution:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This will return 0 through 7 continuously in a thread-safe manner.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and then back to 0.</returns>
    private const int maxIndex = 7; // warning - must be a ([power-of-two number] - 1)
    private static int currentQueueIndex = -1;
    private static int GetNextQueueIndex()
    {
        return Interlocked.Increment(ref currentQueueIndex) & (maxIndex);
    }
```